# Spring Boot JPA Projection of Entity with Postgresql JSON field as Map<Key, Value>

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-types

I'm using Spring Boot with Kotlin and PostgreSQL as DB. For JSON fields I use `hibernate-types-52`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.10.2")
    ...
}
```

I have an entity Address with street JSON field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@TypeDefs(
  TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class),
  TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType::class),
)
data class Address(

  @Id
  var id: Int? = null,

  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(name = "street", columnDefinition = "json", nullable = false)
  var street: Map<Language, String>,
    
  @Column(name = "zip_code" nullable = false)
  var zipCode: String,

  @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @CreationTimestamp
  var createdAt: Date? = null,

  @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
  @UpdateTimestamp
  var updatedAt: Date? = null,
}
```

Corresponding repository is:

```
@Repository
interface AddressRepository : JpaRepository<Address, Int> {

    fun findStreetByZipCode(zipCode: String): AddressStreetOnly?
}
```

Where AddressStreetOnly is an interface:

```
interface AddressStreetOnly {
    val id: Int
    val street: Map<Language, String>
}
```

and Language is an enumeration `enum class Language { EN, RU, KZ, TJ }`

**The problem** is when I call `findStreetByZipCode` the underlying SQL statement has **all fields** in the select query:

```
select
    address0_.id as id1_9_,
    address0_.created_at as created_2_9_,
    address0_.street as street3_9_,
    address0_.updated_at as updated4_9_,
    address0_.zip_code as zip_cod5_9_
from
    addresses
where
    address0_.zip_code = ?
```

But if I change `val street: Map<Language, String>` type in the AddressStreetOnly interface to `val street: Any`, everything works as expected:

```
select
    address0_.id as col_0_0_,
    address0_.street as col_1_0_
from
    addresses
where
    address0_.zip_code = ?
```

I think the problem is in the type of the street field which is Map and it's the Map is forcing to fetch all the fields of the entity. How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you specify the query yourself? So something like
`@Query("select a.zip_code from addresses a where lower(a.zip_code) like lower(:zipCode)")
    
fun findStreet(zipCode: String): AddressStreetOnly?`

Comment: @JipHarthoorn Yes, in that case it works as expected. If I show only necessary fields in select, it generates correct SQL statement. The issue is that I don't want to write queries via `@Query` every time for simple cases where it's possible to write it with JPA method naming approach

Comment: Ah okay, unfortunately I don't know how to do it then